# Open source OCR for Chinese

Tags: open-source, design-patterns, ocr, tesseract

I've searched around for open source OCR for Chinese. But without any luck there rarely seems to be some open source OCR (for Chinese) that are usable.

So I am here wondering:

1. Is there any open source OCR for Chinese that could be used for production environment?
2. What's the main differences when implementing an OCR for Latin-languages and for Chinese? I know some good OCR such as Tesseract or Ocropus, what should I do if I want to make it support Chinese?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose:

- Tesseract 3.0 support chinese/japanese
- NHOCR support japanese

Comment: Is Tesseract 3.0 available for download now? Where can I find its source?

Comment: You can check out http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Chinese has far more characters than Latin languages. There are some commercial products. One of the ways is to contact them and get help.

I don't think there is an open source for Chinese or Japanese characters. In the area of OCR, there are a lot of techniques beyond the pattern recognition algorithms, where a company is good at, not the open source community.

Comment: I did found some open source OCR for Japanese. Seems there is not many choices for Chinese. Still thank you~